How do I fix the overlapping lines in a MUI TextField dropdown with MenuItems
Notice how this drop down has what appears to be multiple outlines surrounding the label.

I'm not sure why that line is at the bottom.  Here's the code:


        <TextField
            select
            label="Gender"
            id="gender1"
            data-testid="gender1"
            {...register("gender1", {
                required: {
                    value: true,
                    message: "Gender is required",
                },
            })}
        >
            {GENDER_OPTIONS.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem value={option}>
                    {option}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </TextField>
        <p className="error">{errors.gender?.message}</p>



And here is what it looks like after selecting an option:

Any help would be appreciated

I had the code snippet reproduced on my end but it rendered correctly without the overflowing border. If you've styled the Textfield, then you might want to include the styling in your question too.

@HamedJimoh the styling I added was the problem.
Thank you
